# How do I invert the color scheme on iterm2?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, iterm2, iterm

I'm using iterm2 (v3.0.14) on Mac Sierra.  How do I invert the color scheme on my terminal?  That is, right now, the default is a black background with white lettering, and I would prefer a white background with black lettering.  Note that I don't want to invert the color scheme for everything on my Mac (which I can do with a keyboard shortcut), I only want to invert the color scheme for iterm2.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the color theme.

1. `preferences>profile>colors>color presets`, choose the scheme or import the scheme you download.
2. Or you can double click the `.itermcolors` files, then go `preferences>profile>colors>color presets` to find your scheme.

If you just want to change the background color and font color, it's more easy. Just adjust the color on `preferences>profile>colors`.

Answer (score -1):

in my case this path helped: Profiles -> Open Profiles -> Edit Profile -> Colours.

Cheers!

Comment: So what you are saying is "Thanks for the existing answer" ? Otherwise please make more obvious which additional insight your post provides to the solution.